# PHP Phalcon - Displaying Content

Tags: javascript, php, phalcon

Im trying to create a easy upload script with Phalcon PHP but im not sure how to approach it.

I have a controller with the following code, as you can see in the indexAction function i have im just trying to output simple text onto the page but it is not working. Do i have to use another function or something?

```
class ManagerController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function initialize(){


    }
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if(function_exists('loadServer')){
            echo "It works";
        }else {
            echo "Not Working";
        }
    }

    public $errorMsg = null;
    const DOWNLOAD_TOKEN_VAR = 'download_token';


    //public function download($forceDownload = null, $downloadToken = null);
    public function loadServer()
    {
        echo 'Hello Welcome!';
    }
}
```

And here is my index volt file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Phalcon PHP Framework</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ content() }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shoud use: method_exists($this,'loadServer') http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out i still need help figuring out how to display on the page.

Comment: What happens when you go to http://websiteurl/manager

Comment: use "exit;" after echo line to see the output directly from controllers..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a view Phalcon will not display your echos.

Simply remove your view and the echo will work or set a variable via

```
$this->view->setVar('hello',"Hello World!");
```

and change view to match

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Phalcon PHP Framework</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            {{ hello }}
        </body>
    </html>
```